# simple AI with a handler?

Tags: java, android

I've made a main class including 2 players tic tac toe. 
Now I made a new class that extends the main class but a human against a simple AI.
In the new class I am using a thread with a handler that checks if it's human's turn, if it's not it is supposed to make a random move. The problem is that my handler never executes.

```
public class EasyAI extends MainActivity{

Thread thread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    thread = new Thread(new moveAI());
    thread.start();
}

class moveAI implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Looper.prepare();
        if(isMyTurn == false)      //isMyTurn is a public variable in Main class
        {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   moveAI();
                }
            },500);
        }
    }
}  

public void moveAI(){...}
} // end class
```

I know I am doing something wrong. I hope you get my idea. But how can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me ask you a question. Why are you using concurrency for this? As far as I can see you're adding additional complexity where it's not needed.

Next this snippet isn't enough to detect the problem. It could be something concurrency related (for example isMyTurn is not marked volatile and thread executing moveAI is caching false version in processor cache since compiler could optimize it)

Maybe your moveAI exits early. Try adding some debugging output.

Comment: because i am a newbiew and trying dangerous things

Comment: That's the spirit :P.

In this case concurrency is quite dangerous and when designing system try to either avoid it or use already implemented helpers (such as ExecutorService)